# ADXL355 Axes Overflowing

Tags: raspberry-pi, c, accelerometer

I am using an ADXL355 accelerometer on an ADXL355Z evaluation board and an RPI Zero W communicating over SPI, with [datasheet here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adxl354_355.pdf).

I previously had it producing stable g values (with other issues as detailed [here (irrelevant to this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036735/adxl355-accelerometer-axes-seemingly-coupled-and-offset) but that has since stopped.

Upon disconnecting the RPI for a few days and coming back to it, things no longer work correctly. The accelerometer seems to be overflowing on its axes when it is turned, as detailed below.
I have rebuilt the code, and run a fresh install of Raspbian, but the issue has persisted.

Testing sequence:
[image: Testing methodology]

Acceleration values measured, on the slow swing up to 90 degrees (back down again is not included in this graph)
It looks like the acceleration values are reaching 8g, then looping back to -8g, before repeating the whole cycle.
[image: Acceleration data]

**My code:**

```
/****** Include Files ******/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> // Contains information about integer values of different bit lengths etc.
#include <ctype.h>

/****** Register Maps ******/
#define DEVID_AD                 0x00
#define DEVID_MST                0x01
#define PARTID                   0x02
#define REVID                    0x03
#define STATUS                   0x04
#define FIFO_ENTRIES             0x05
#define TEMP2                    0x06
#define TEMP1                    0x07
#define XDATA3                   0x08
#define XDATA2                   0x09
#define XDATA1                   0x0A
#define YDATA3                   0x0B
#define YDATA2                   0x0C
#define YDATA1                   0x0D
#define ZDATA3                   0x0E
#define ZDATA2                   0x0F
#define ZDATA1                   0x10
#define FIFO_DATA                0x11
#define OFFSET_X_H               0x1E
#define OFFSET_X_L               0x1F
#define OFFSET_Y_H               0x20
#define OFFSET_Y_L               0x21
#define OFFSET_Z_H               0x22
#define OFFSET_Z_L               0x23
#define ACT_EN                   0x24
#define ACT_THRESH_H             0x25
#define ACT_THRESH_L             0x26
#define ACT_COUNT                0x27
#define FILTER                   0x28
#define FIFO_SAMPLES             0x29
#define INT_MAP                  0x2A
#define SYNC                     0x2B
#define RANGE                    0x2C
#define POWER_CTL                0x2D
#define SELF_TEST                0x2E
#define RESET                    0x2F

/****** Interface Constants ******/
#define WRITE_BIT                0x00
#define READ_BIT                 0x01
#define DUMMY_BYTE               0x69
#define ADDR_ARRAY_SIZE          10
#define STANDBY_MODE             0x01
#define ACTIVE_MODE              0x00

/****** Conversion Constants ******/
#define G_FACTOR_R2G             0.0000039f // Better to add an "f" on the end and use floats the entire time?
#define G_FACTOR_R4G             0.0000078f
#define G_FACTOR_R8G             0.0000156f

/****** Configuration Constants ******/
#define RANGE_2G                 0b01
#define RANGE_4G                 0b10
#define RANGE_8G                 0b11

const int speedSPI = 2000000;  // SPI communication speed, bps
const int coldStartSamples = 2;  // number of samples to be read before outputting data to console (cold start delays)
const double coldStartDelay = 0.1;  // time delay between cold start reads
const int adxl355ValuesPayloadBytes = 9;
const double delay = 0.1;
static char accAdr[ADDR_ARRAY_SIZE] = {(XDATA1 << 1) | READ_BIT, 
                                       (XDATA2 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (XDATA3 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (YDATA1 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (YDATA2 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (YDATA3 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (ZDATA1 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (ZDATA2 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       (ZDATA3 << 1) | READ_BIT,
                                       DUMMY_BYTE};


int readOneByte(int handle, char addr, char* readByte)
{
   char data[2];
   data[0] = (addr << 1) | READ_BIT;
   data[1] = DUMMY_BYTE;
   int bytes = spiXfer(handle, data, data, 2);
   if (bytes != 2){ // Check right number of bytes read
      return -1;
   }
   *readByte = data[1];
   return 0;
}

int writeOneByte(int handle, char byte, char addr)
{
   char data[2];
   data[0] = (addr << 1) |  WRITE_BIT;
   data[1] = byte;
   int bytes = spiXfer(handle, data, data, 2);
   char checkRead; // Should this then be a char pointer?
   readOneByte(handle, addr, &checkRead);
   if (bytes != 2){ // Check right number of bytes written
      return -1;
   } else if (checkRead != byte){ // Check that byte was written correctly
      return -2;
   }
   return 0;
}

int readAccData(int handle, char* accReadings){
   return spiXfer(handle, accAdr, accReadings, ADDR_ARRAY_SIZE);
}

int concatenateBytes(char* accReadings, int32_t* x, int32_t* y, int32_t* z)
{
   // Cast, shift, zero, combine:
   *x = ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[3])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[2])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[1])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F);
   *y = ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[6])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[5])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[4])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F);
   *z = ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[9])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[8])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((uint32_t)(accReadings[7])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F);
   return 0;
}

int concatenateBytesChar(char* accReadings, int* x, int* y, int* z)
{
   // Cast, shift, zero, combine:
   *x = (int32_t)(((((accReadings[3])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((accReadings[2])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((accReadings[1])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F));
   *y = (int32_t)(((((accReadings[6])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((accReadings[5])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((accReadings[4])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F));
   *z = (int32_t)(((((accReadings[9])) << 12) & 0x000FF000) | ((((accReadings[8])) << 4) & 0x00000FF0) | ((((accReadings[7])) >> 4) & 0x0000000F));
   return 0;
}

int twoCompCompat(int* toConv)
{
    if ((*toConv & 0x80000) == 0x80000)
    {
        *toConv |= 0xFFF00000;
    }
    return 0;
}

int adxl355_startup()
{
    // Sensor initialization
    printf("Running startup\n");
    int h, bytes, success;
    h = spiOpen(0, speedSPI, 0);
    if (h < 0){
    return -1;
    }
    char readByte = '\0';
    readOneByte(h, DEVID_AD, &readByte);
    printf("DEVID_AD = %x\n", readByte);
    readByte = '\0';
    readOneByte(h, DEVID_MST, &readByte);
    printf("DEVID_MST = %x\n", readByte);


    // Writing range value
    printf("Writing range value\n");
    writeOneByte(h, RANGE_8G, RANGE);
    readByte = '\0';
    readOneByte(h, RANGE, &readByte);
    printf("Range value: %x\n", readByte);
    // if (writeOneByte(h, RANGE_8G, RANGE) != 0){
    //     printf("Range value not written correctly\n");
    // }

    // Writing filter value to the filter register
    printf("Writing filter value\n");
    writeOneByte(h, 0x05, FILTER);
    readByte = '\0';
    readOneByte(h, FILTER, &readByte);
    printf("Filter value: %x\n", readByte);
    if (readByte != 0x07){
        printf("Filter value not written correctly\n");
    }

    // Writing power mode to the power mode register
    printf("Writing power control value\n");
    writeOneByte(h, ACTIVE_MODE, POWER_CTL);
    readByte = '\0';
    readOneByte(h, POWER_CTL, &readByte);
    printf("Power control value: %x\n", readByte);
    if (readByte != ACTIVE_MODE){
        printf("Power mode value not written correctly\n");
    }

    return h;
}

int main()
{
    gpioInitialise();
    if (gpioInitialise() < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GPIO\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int h = adxl355_startup();
    printf("Startup success\n");

    printf("Reading 10 samples\n");
    int x, y, z;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){ // Reading a lot more samples for a larger graph
        char accReadings[ADDR_ARRAY_SIZE];
        readAccData(h, accReadings);
        // printf("\n\n%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\n", accReadings[1], accReadings[2], accReadings[3], accReadings[4], accReadings[5], accReadings[6], accReadings[7], accReadings[8], accReadings[9]);
        concatenateBytesChar(accReadings, &x, &y, &z);
        // To two's complement.
        // printf("%x %x %x\n", x, y, z);
        // printf("%i %i %i\n", x, y, z);
        twoCompCompat(&x);
        twoCompCompat(&y);
        twoCompCompat(&z);
        // printf("%i %i %i\n", x, y, z);
        printf("%f %f %f\n", G_FACTOR_R8G*x, G_FACTOR_R8G*y, G_FACTOR_R8G*z);
        time_sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your input data are shifted left some bits. This produces staircase functions like this where lower bits become sign bits. Is the SPI bit stream scrolled?

Comment: @Jens Aka the data I am reading from the accelerometer is left shifted a bit? I'm not sure what a scrolled SPI stream means either :D

Comment: This "scrolled" data was my first thougt, then I wrote the full explanation in my answer. The data array is indeed scrolled by two byte in the decoder window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding in the multibyte read function. You made an array of adresses you want to read in a sequence and expect, that the chip will answer the content of each register in return. This is not how it works.

In a multibyte read sequence you only provide the start register address, all following bytes you send are ignored, could be anything. They are only needed to provide the clock timing for the transfer.

The chip answeres first with the content of the start register and then increments the address on each byte read that follows. So it delivers a linear array of register values, where you only can define the start and the number of bytes.

The first address you send is XDATA1 (= register 0x0A), and this way you receive the register content from 0x0A - 0x13. This is far away from what you expected since you miss two bytes from the X data and everything is scrolled by two bytes.

To correct this, the first byte in the array "accAdr" should be "(XDATA3 << 1) | READ_BIT" and the rest of the array can be filled with garbage like you already have declared ("DUMMY_BYTE").

I recommend to use the FIFO feature, so you don't miss data and if you decode the EMPTY bit in the FIFO answer correctly, you won't read a value twice. This would provide a synchronous data stream.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, and all three "issues" were resolved as soon as I added this so many thanks! As regards FIFO, it is then something one reads less often than the frequency of the accelerometer updating it, so that one reads whole chunks of data at a time?